# Limiting inner associations in Rails 3 (ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one to one association with the following active record model (example):

```
User <-1-1-> employee <-1-1-> contact <-1-1-> 
permanentAddress contact <-1-1-> communicationAddress
```

When the query fires using ActiveRecord:

```
User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "49"]]
  Employeedetail Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "employeedetails".* FROM "employeedetails" WHERE "employeedetails"."User_id" = 49 LIMIT 1
  Contactdetail Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "contactdetails".* FROM "contactdetails" WHERE "contactdetails"."employeedetail_id" = 40 LIMIT 1
  Address Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."contactdetail_id" = 52 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."contactdetail_id" = 52 LIMIT 1
```

Question : How to increase the `LIMIT` to 2 for addresses table `[inner association]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to override the limit in this has_one and belongs_to case because by default the SQL that would be fired when we write user.employer has LIMIT 1 constraint set on it...if you want that a contact has two address then you should change the relationship from has_one to has_many and then apply the limit of 2 on it using validations...

Comment: thanks for your suggesting that is working now , only problem is that now , i am getting unordered data . that i have to fix now ,if you have some suggestion please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limit` :

```
Address.limit(2).where("contactdetail_id = ?", 52)
```

So, it will return first 2 Address have contactdetail_id = 52. See more [Limit and Offset](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset).

Comment: is there any way to override this method ?

Comment: why do you want to override?, if you want more than this, i think you should write your own SQL query.